# Using JQuery to add another field and update hidden field, only working one way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JSFiddle link :[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27ypfxba/)

I have created a script using two examples I have found to do two different things, one add new fields at the users request as well as update a hidden field to show how many have been created. This is working if you add fields, i.e. the hidden field changes from 1 to 2 to 3... as the extra fields appear, but when you click remove this doesn't scale down properly below 2 and not always at all.

Any suggestions as to where I have gone wrong:

HTML:

```
<input id="bacon" type="hidden" class="bacon" value="1" name="testinput">
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                $('input#bacon').val(i);
                i++;
                return false;

        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        $('input#bacon').val(i);
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: if( i > 2 ) in remove?

Comment: Go onto the jsfiddle, thats what makes the remove function work, in putting the change of hidden value in there I expected it to keep changing from 3,2,1 but it stops at 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `live()` has been deprecated and removed from jQuery several years ago, use `on()` with a current version of jQuery instead.
`size()` shouldn't be used either, you should be using `length`, and `parents()` isn't a good choice ... ever.

Secondly, you're creating elements with the same ID multiple times.

You should be checking the length of the collection, or in other words actually check how many elements there are on the page, and use that count whenever new elements are inserted or removed.

Try something more like this, it uses a more jQuery'ish syntax to create the element, which lets you add the event handler for removing directly.

```js
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var i = $('.scents').length + 1,
            p = $('<p />', {
                'class': 'scents'
            }),
            l = $('<label />', {
                'for': 'p_scnts' + i
            }),
            f = $('<input />', {
                type : 'text',
                id   : 'p_scnt' + i,
                name : 'p_scnt' + i,
                size : '20',
                placeholder: "Input Value"
            }),
            a = $('<a />', {
                href: "#",
                text: 'Remove',
                on: {
                    click: function() {
                        p.remove();
                        $('#bacon').val($('.scents').length + 1);
                    }
                }
            });

        scntDiv.append(p.append(l.append(f), a));
        $('#bacon').val(i + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="bacon" class="bacon" value="1" name="testinput">
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
  <p>
    <label for="p_scnts">
      <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
    </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27ypfxba/1/) a little bit. I:

1. Removed the i > 2
2. Redifined the value of i (i-- and i++) **before** the value of i was updated in the input.
3. Removed the "+ 1" in the first definition of i.

Some explanation:
If the user click the add-input button, your script adds the button to the page, adds 1 to the value of i, and "stored" the value in the input. So, it looks something like this:

```
$("form").append(/*new input*/); 
i++; 
$("input").val(i);
```

If the user deletes an input, the input is removed, i is decreased by 1, and the value is "stored" in the input:

```
$("input").remove();
i--;
$("input").val(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
        --i;
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                $('input#bacon').val(i);

        }
        return false;
});
```

Comment: it now doesn't work at all, please provide a jsfiddle link if you have one

Comment: have you tried this fiddle , just decrement i on before

Comment: Code-only answers are less helpful, both to the OP and to future visitors. Please put effort into explaining why your solution works, and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase/decrease i before updating the value because otherwise you still have the old value of i stored in the input. And it will update only on the next call of the function. When you update the i before updating the input, the input gets updated in that exact function call, not in the next
And therefore you also don't need the +1 when initializing i

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size();

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            $('input#bacon').val(i);
            return false;

    });

    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
            if( i > 1 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
                    $('input#bacon').val(i);
            }
            return false;
    });
```

});